# How to intercept access token in Spring mvc app?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, single-sign-on, spring-oauth2

I would like to intercept the access token from every requests in my Spring MVC web app, after the user authenticated using Single Sign On from OAuth2 Provider. My demo app code is currently like below:

application.yml:

```
security:
  oauth2:
    client:
      clientId: metlife_monitor
      clientSecret: password
      accessTokenUri: http://localhost:8668/sso-server/oauth/token
      userAuthorizationUri: http://localhost:8668/sso-server/oauth/authorize
      tokenName: oauth_token
    resource:
      userInfoUri: http://localhost:8688/api/me
```

SpringBoot Application.java:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableOAuth2Sso
@EnableJdbcHttpSession
public class App1Application  extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .antMatcher("/**")
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/login**", "/login2**", "/error**", "/webjars/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().logout()
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("http://localhost:8668/sso-server/logout")
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .deleteCookies("client-session", "JSESSIONID")
                .permitAll()
                .and().csrf().disable()
        ;

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App1Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

DashboardController.java:

```
@Controller
public class DashboardController {
    @GetMapping("/")
    public ModelAndView home() {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("index");
        return modelAndView;
    }

    @GetMapping("/protected")
    public ModelAndView protectedView() {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("protected");
        return modelAndView;
    }
}
```

Comment: Depending on you use-case, you can either use a [GenericFilterBean](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/GenericFilterBean.html) or a [HandlerInterceptor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerInterceptor.html)

Answer (score 0):

Register a [`OncePerRequestFilter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/OncePerRequestFilter.html) then on the `doFilterInternal` method extract the token from the request.

```
@Component
public class TokenInterceptorFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

  @Autowired
  private AuthenticationStorage storage;

  @Override
  protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
          FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {

    // Extract the token from the request

    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
  }

}
```